# Eclipse Common Navigator Framework

Tags: eclipse, file, editor, cnf

I have an Eclipse Common Navigator (specific to our project ) on our RAP application.
So, generally, when user a resource in the left hand side navigator, it gets opened in the right hand side navigator.Now,suppose, if a click a file with some extension, I want to open a custom message opened and popped up in front of the user in the form of a Dialog Box.
how can I achieve this

Comment: when you say "it gets opened in the right hand side navigator" do you mean it gets opened in an editor?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Alternatively you can register a specific editor with an associated launcher:

```
<editor
        id="com.foo.MyEditor"
        launcher="com.foo.MyEditorLauncher"
        default="true"
        extensions="your_extension_here"
        icon="any icon for your file"
        name="Dialog editor">
 </editor>
```

And implement the launcher to show the dialog you want:

```
public class MyEditorLauncher implements IEditorLauncher {
    @Override
    public void open(IPath path) {
        Shell shell = Display.getDefault().getActiveShell();
        MessageDialog.openInformation(shell, "Not Editable", "Can't open this element");
    }
}
```

The user will be always be able to use alternative editors, but by default they'll get that message.

Comment: Thanks for your interest Jaime ,

Answer (score 0):

You will want to register an editor via the editors extension point against files of that extension. The body of that editor can be the message that you want.

Comment: No , my requirement is that when user clicks on files of certain extension, an error message Box should be popped up saying that files with extension(for example ".cert") cannot be opened.

Comment: I just require a message Box, I don't want an editor to open all.Please help me.

Answer (score 0):

Try registering an ActionProvider in the navigatorContent with the appropiated enablement (so that it is applied to the files you're interested in).

Within your custom action provider (extending CommonActionProvider) you can subscribe to the doubleclick events in the init method:

```
@Override
public void init(ICommonActionExtensionSite aSite) {
    super.init(aSite);
    IWorkbench workbench = MyPlugin.getDefault().getWorkbench();
    doubleclick = new IDoubleClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void doubleClick(DoubleClickEvent event) {
            // show Your Popup Here !!!
        }
    };
    aSite.getStructuredViewer().addDoubleClickListener(doubleclick);
}
```

Comment: This should happen only for selective items, and not all items in Navigator.Up on double click on any resource,an open action (custom defined ) occurs, How  can I selective configure some items, so that up on their double click,message box pops up