# handling events in Package explorer Eclipse

Tags: eclipse-plugin, event-handling, package-explorer

I want to stop user from modifying selected file in the package explorer while my plugin is running.

A custom message should popup if the user tries to change the file.

Answer (score 0):

Implement your own editor launcher (`IEditorLauncher`), which would show this message and associate it with the files you don't want to be modified.

See an example in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5444674/eclipse-common-navigator-framework) SO question.

Another possible approach is to simply now show these files in Package explorer (similary to hiding .class files by Java plugin).

Comment: Thanks dreo for the interest i will post my queries on the link suggested.